# Oracle Weblogic generic installer 10.3.5 hangs on "Specify Security Updates Screen"

Tags: java, oracle, installation, weblogic

SUSE SLES11 SP3 x86_64 on a test machine here. I'm trying to install Oracle Weblogic 10.3.5 with generic installer but I always run in this well-known situation:

"Occasionally, the Oracle WebLogic Server or Oracle HTTP Server installation process hangs on the Specify Security Updates screen (5 of 9) in the NextGen Oracle Universal Installer (OUI). When this occurs, all of the buttons at the bottom of the OUI screen are disabled and inaccessible and the links to go back in the left-hand pane are similarly inactive."

Oracle docs suggest this woraround: "When this situation occurs, you must forcibly exit the installer by pressing CTRL-C in the xterm where you initially launched the installer. You can then restart and walk through the installation normally." Unfortunately this happens again and again.

I tried with java 1.6 and 1.7 but no luck.

Any suggestion?

TIA - Cristian

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and found that when it was stuck at the “Specify Security Updates Screen”, the installer was trying to access lb-ccr.oracle.com:https  (141.146.54.49:443). The fix was to temporarily configure the following firewall rule:

iptables -I OUTPUT -d 141.146.54.49 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable

After configuring this and restarting the installer, at the same step, I was asked about a proxy to connect to the Internet but also gave me the option the continue installer without subscribing. Guess what I did next? :)

When the installer finishes, delete the rule from iptables using:

iptables -D OUTPUT -d 141.146.54.49 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable

Another option would be to use a silent install using and XML file with installation options.